# Fuzzy selection / magic wand on a UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, crop, cgimage

I'm been looking for days for a way to let the user select part of a photograph to cut out (like a person). I have the cutting working, however it's up to the user to draw the area to cut.
Are there any libraries available that will do fuzzy selection to automatically plot around an object in a UIImage? Similar to Photoshops magic wand tool.

Thanks

Comment: Andy Finnel has a nice write up for developing this on Mac. It looks like it would port fairly easily to iOS. http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/

Comment: Thanks Rob, I had seen that however the code is 6 years old and no longer works. I will read through the lengthy post which seems to be very detailed, however i'm not sure I know enough about image manipulation to get it working.

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Darren can you suggest me some example how can i achieve this. i also have same problem. I found iMagickWand but because of some library problem unable to achieve. Please help me.

Comment: I just used iMagickWand in the end.

Comment: @Darren Can you tell how did you allow the user to draw on image and cut that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this on github, might help: https://github.com/ap4y/iMagickWand

Comment: @Darren do you have this above link code? Actually now the code have some missing files and it does not runs.

Comment: No sorry. Did you do a proper git checkout and update sub modules? Instead of just grabbing the zip?

Comment: I am getting Getting error as MagicWand.h not found.Can you please suggest me how to make it work?

Comment: hi Darren, have we solved the problem of implementing magic wand on swift? If so, can you share it with me, because I'm really having a hard time right now. Thank you